How can I get the Status of an Azure SQL MI using powershell or REST API?
I am trying to get the status of Azure SQL MI however the Get-AzSqlInstance does not return the status. If running or stopped. What is the easiest way to get this?

Get-AzResource works. State is found under "properties"

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
